# Is it possible to store "multidimensional" arrays in a json file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store a "multidimensional array" in a json file read by javaScript, which is actually just an array with multiple arrays in it. Is this possible? If so how? I tried writing it the same way as in javascipt, that wouldn't work, but maybe there is something else wrong with the code. Here is my JSON file:

```
    {
    "HTML": [['button','level1Button','position:absolute; top:100px; left:200px;','LEVEL I','loadLevel(1)',false,false],['a','howtoplayhref','position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px;','how to play',false,false,'howtoplay.html']],
    "levelObjects": "StillEmptyForNow"
    }
```

Comment: Why not write in in JS and then use `JSON.stringify()` to see how its supposed to be? The short answer is yes, this is possible, the long answer is probably syntax related.

Comment: Did you try changing your single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: *A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in **double quotes**, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.*

Comment: @BradleyMHandy Thanks, I changed them to double quotes and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

MinusFour is correct, JSON requires double quotes:

```
var a = {"myarr": [["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"]]} 
a["myarr"][1][1]
> "b2"

var a = {"HTML": [["button","level1Button","position:absolute; top:100px; left:200px;","LEVEL I","loadLevel(1)",false,false],["a","howtoplayhref","position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px;","how to play",false,false,"howtoplay.html"]]}

a["HTML"][1][1]
> "howtoplayhref"
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your JSON in to the console and put the obligatory `var x=` in front of it and it worked just fine. then with a `JSON.stringify(x,null,'  ')` was gifted with the following:

```js
var x=
{
  "HTML": [
    [
      "button",
      "level1Button",
      "position:absolute; top:100px; left:200px;",
      "LEVEL I",
      "loadLevel(1)",
      false,
      false
    ],
    [
      "a",
      "howtoplayhref",
      "position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px;",
      "how to play",
      false,
      false,
      "howtoplay.html"
    ]
  ],
  "levelObjects": "StillEmptyForNow"
}

JSONtext.innerHTML=JSON.stringify(x,null,'  ')
```

```html
<pre id='JSONtext'></pre>
```